# Execute function with dplyr syntax across a list using lapply

Tags: r, dplyr

My goal is to run a function across two lists using mapply.
Here is a MWE.

```
library(mtcars)
plot.plot  <- function(var, title=""){
    mtcars %>%
        select({{var}}, carb) %>%
        group_by(carb, {{var}})%>%
        count() %>%
        ggplot(mapping=aes(x=carb, y=freq))+
        geom_bar(stat="identity")
}
```

My goal is then to use something like that

```
list.var <- list("vs", "am", "gear")
list.title <- list("a", "b", "c")

mapply(var=list.var, title=list.title, plot.plot)
```

, which perfectly works using base R. However, I'm struggling with the quotes of `list.var`.

The function `plot.plot(vs)` works fine. But I cannot create a list like `list(vs, am, gear)` I could run mapply across.

Comment: It would make more sense to store your variables as proper symbols/expressions rather than strings in this case. `list.var <- rlang::exprs(vs, am, gear)` or `list.var <- rlang::syms(c("vs", "am", "gear"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider changing the function to take either quoted or unquoted variable by replacing the `{{}}` with `ensym` + `!!`

```
plot.plot  <- function(var, title=""){
    var <- rlang::ensym(var)
    mtcars %>%
        count(carb, !!var) %>%          
        ggplot(mapping=aes(x=carb, y=n))+
        geom_bar(stat="identity")
}
```

The summarised column created with `count` is named as `n` and not `Freq`.  Also, the `group_by`  + `select` can be removed and just use `count` with columns directly specified on it

-testing with `map2`

```
library(purrr)
out <- map2(list.var, list.title, plot.plot)
```

Comment: `.data[[var]]` is a shorthand for `!! ensym(var)`

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing variables as string you can use `.data` to refer variable names.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

plot.plot  <- function(var, title=""){
  mtcars %>%
    count(carb, .data[[var]]) %>%
    ggplot(mapping=aes(x=carb, y=n))+
    geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
    ggtitle(title)
}

list.var <- list("vs", "am", "gear")
list.title <- list("a", "b", "c")

list_plot <- Map(plot.plot, list.var, list.title)
```

Access individual plots using `list_plot[[1]]`, `list_plot[[2]]` etc.